# How to add bootstrap 5 and other global packages to a SvelteKit project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, svelte, sveltekit

I installed *bootstrap* using *NPM*

In a normal `svelte` project I usualy add *bootstrap* and other packages, which are used project wide, in the `App.ts` file. However, in a *SvelteKit* project there is no main entry point.

So what is the recommended way of adding *bootstrap 5* or other *packages* to *SvelteKit* globally?

I don't want to use rollup plugins, but rather just want to import it as an *module* in `JavaScript`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of SvelteKit 1.0, the easiest way I found to add static scripts and styles that will be available everywhere is to add them to

```
src/app.html
```

That is the file that includes everything else including the `<html>` tag, so you can place the styles in the `<head>` and the scripts in the `<body>`, including CDN URLs, like you have always done before.

This setup allows you to easily override Bootstrap settings, e.g. I added a style to `unset` the `<body>`'s `background-color` that is set by Bootstrap.

To host the scripts yourself rather than use a CDN, put them in the `src/static` directory and reference them using the prefix `%sveltekit.assets%/`.  For example, I placed the files `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` in `src/static/bootstrap-5.0.2/` so now my `src/app.html` file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        %sveltekit.head%

        <link href="%sveltekit.assets%/res/bootstrap-5.0.2/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                /* override Bootstrap */
                background-color: unset;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
        
        <script src="%sveltekit.assets%/res/bootstrap-5.0.2/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to use a CDN instead of self hosting the files then for e.g. for Bootstrap 5.0.2 you can use the following:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I just faced this issue, since, for some reason, collapses and modals didn't work using sveltestrap or svelte-add, and I didn't want to add a cdn, thanks for your solution :)

Comment: In Sveltekit 1.0 the "static" directory is in the root, not inside "src". The code above is correct.

Comment: I set this as accepted anwser, because the question was asked when svelte was still in beta. This is now indeed how it should be done, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

**updated answer for SvelteKit > 1.0**

The previous answer, while correct at the time of asking, has been outdated since a major refactor to SvelteKit prior to that release (but *after* posting the answer)

The top level layout layout is now a file called `+layout.svelte` instead.

**previous answer**

You can make a top level `__layout` and import everything there.

Comment: Seems like that is the way, also found out there is `svelte-add`, which seems to be the future but doesnt have alot of packages currently.

Answer (score 3):

I add this because this seems to be a good way for adding packages to a *SvelteKit* app.

https://github.com/svelte-add/svelte-add

If you want to add *Bootstrap* for example use

```
npx svelte-add@latest bootstrap
```

As of date of writing this, there are not alot of packages yet, hopefully that changes in the future.

Comment: how to choose bootstrap 4 or bootstrap 5?

Comment: Looking at the source of the *bootstrap* package you can't, https://github.com/svelte-add/bootstrap/blob/main/__run.js#L5 It just adds `bootstrap` without the option to add a version, so it just installs the latest version of *bootstrap*. Would be nice indeed if they added the ability to specify which version.

Comment: Btw, I would just go for the good old `npm install bootstrap@version` way. Since sveltekit has the top level `__layout` now.

Comment: @NamGVU I actualy forgot something, you can change the version of bootstrap by just simply changing the version in your *package.json*.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly run `npm install bootstrap` inside your sveltekit project.

Then

In your root `+layout.svelte` put

```
<script>
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js';
</script>
```

References

- https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#css
- https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#explicit-url-imports

Comment: This is now the best answer for SvelteKit. If you use svelte-add to install Bootstrap, the Bootstrap SCSS will already be imported in `+layout.svelte`. Just add the JS import for components. Note that `dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js`is also available if you also need Popper for dropdowns, popovers, or tooltips. Or import individual JS components from `js/dist/*.js`.

Comment: Does not seem to work with latest SvelteKit:
"document is not defined"