# Importing Bootstrap SvelteKit without "document is not defined" error

Tags: node.js, bootstrap-5, sveltekit

EDIT : See duplicate answer, the SSR compatible code at the bottom works for me.

I've been looking for a proper way to import Bootstrap into a SvelteKit project, where Bootstrap is installed using npm. Importing the CSS is quite straightforward since I prefer compiling the CSS file using SASS. I create a file in `src/assets/scss` named `main.scss` (here's an example based on Bootstrap's "Option A" - note the extra `../../`):

```
@import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

This is compiled to `src/static/css/main.css` and then imported in the `app.html` file.

`app.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" /> <!-- HERE -->
        %sveltekit.head%
    </head>
    <body data-sveltekit-preload-data="hover">
        <div style="display: contents">%sveltekit.body%</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So far so good. Things get trickier when trying to import Bootstrap from `node_modules`. There are different Stackoverflow answers (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75272446/12421409)) that claim you can simply import `bootstrap.min.js` in the `script` tag. However, this gives me a "document is not defined" error. I understand this is because the document has not yet loaded - SvelteKit provides the `browser` module to get around this. I can import Bootstrap properly with the following code:

```
<script>
    import { browser } from '$app/environment';
    
    let bootstrap;
    async function loadBootstrap() {
        bootstrap = await import('bootstrap');

        // do stuff with bootstrap here
    }
    if (browser) loadBootstrap();
</script>
```

While this works, I have to repeat the same lines of code every time I want to instantiate Bootstrap, for example when I want to manually show a modal. I'm wondering if there's a reason why the solution provided in the above Stackoverflow answer doesn't work, and if it's wrong, whether I could be loading Bootstrap in a cleaner way.